# creating an javascript object at global level

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to create an object like below

var x = function x() {};

Does this create an object at window level/global level.Is it good way of using it ?

Comment: Without the surrounding code there is no way to answer that.  If you use `window.x = function() {}` then it *will* be global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this was written in the global name space.. meaning in a loaded script directly or in a script tag this will be global.

But if this was made inside, for example, a dom ready event or an onlad event handlers this wont be global.

Using window.variable makes it global even if you're inside any block.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Just to make sure i have used the above snippet like below .Will then be it is considered as global ?

var x = function x() {};

x.set_Data = function(data){
  this.data = data;
};

function y(){
/*i guess x is global */
  var f = x.data;
 alert(f);
}

Comment: If it's directly under <script type="text/javascript"> var x = function x() {}; ...